# Excel conditional formatting and matching

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'd like to automatically conditionally format a group of cells based on dates in another sheet.  I've included an example table:

[image]

... where I've manually highlighted in yellow each quarter that the institution matched the date range in the other sheet's matching table:

[image]

**Is this possible automatically or is manual formatting the only option?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using VBA. 
You will need to create a “helper column” on your main sheet with this formula:

```
="Q" & INT((MONTH(Sheet2!A1)+2)/3) & MOD(YEAR(Sheet2!A1),100) & "/" & Sheet2!B1
```

This will yield data that look like this:

```
Q216/Fidelity
Q116/Fidelity
Q415/Fidelity
Q316/Wellington
Q316/Janus
```

I changed “31-Dec-16” to “31-Dec-**15**” in the last “Fidelity” row
because I assume that’s what you meant. 
Let’s say that the above is in Sheet1, Column `Z`. 
Then do your conditional formatting with the formula

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(B$1 & "/" & $A2,$Z:$Z, 0)))
```

This builds strings that look like `Q316/Fidelity`
and searches for them in Column `Z`,
and evaluates to TRUE if they are found.

Comment: I was thinking of a reverse solution. Find the dates in that quarter and match it to the second table.  I like this better.

Answer (score 0):

**It's certainly possible to do this automatically.**

Excel uses VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) for Macros, and this is a pretty decent programming language. But, because this is going to require programming, it isn't necessarily going to be easy.

I'm guessing you'll need two main stages to your macro:

1. Match specific dates to quarters
2. Identify the Institutions and Quarters (row and column address) that need to be highlighted.

Start by recording a macro and then edit it to get into the code side of things, then start breaking your problem down into the component steps and developing the code to accomplish each.

As you come across issues you cannot solve, come back here with your specific questions and we'll be happy to help.